# Building a dynamic component loader with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Basically i want to create a dynamic plugin system. I need to be able to deploy new plugins without having to redeploy the main plugin system.

Basically if I was to use SystemJS i could just do something like

```
System.import(url).then(plugin => {
  this.createComponent(plugin.default);
});
```

`url` being the dynamic thing - could read this from a db or config, etc.

The above could would work - except i use the Angular CLI, which uses Webpack. Using the CLI is a choice made to simply the whole project - so I'm stuck with Webpack and the CLI.

Since the Angular CLI does a lot of abstraction, I can't modify the webpack config (well I can, but then i have to maintain it manually, which again would break the simplicity).

Webpack is not a module loading, but a bundler - meaning it is supposed to know these modules beforehand, and i can't just drop a new module somewhere and update the config for it to load it dynamically.

What would my options be here?

EDIT: Webpack has its own System.import, but it has some checking to see if the url is static or dynamic. I could live with passing a static folder and having to drop plugins into that folder - that just doesn't seem to work from anywhere but inside the application itself.

Comment: Had the same requirement when we started a year ago. There was no choice but to use systemjs and not use the angular-cli. I don't see anything since then that would allow the cli to work more "dynamically" but would like to know if there is.

Comment: _Webpack is not a module loading, but a bundler_ - that's exactly right, so there should be no choice between Webpack and SystemJS, use both. They are different tools for different tasks. I'm working on a plugin based system and use both now

Comment: @Maximus yeah, but a little worried SystemJS would be overkill - also i would need to hack it somehow to override webpacks System.import. It irks me some...

Comment: @Maximus how do you deal with `entryComponents` when loading components dynamically ?

Comment: @SystemJS follows the proposal for [dynamic modules loading](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_module-loader-api) so it should be availble in browsers over time anyway. Also the article  [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) might help you with your journey

Comment: I would be REALLY surprised if anyone could solve this problem really

Comment: @Milad, we require third party vendors to package them into a module and then we load the module when bootstrapping the app. The other way could be to load compiled component factories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, at the end of the day you need to add your dynamic component to the `entryComponents` of the current module, otherwise Angular won't let you load it dynamically and it will complain.

So either way, you've got to load the component statically and put it inside the `entryComponents`, so not much point in using SystemJS or Something else, you could just create a dictionary and use it when ever you want :

import {MyComponentClass} from 'somewhere';

```
const dictionary = {
    component1  = MyComponentClass
}

 this.createComponent(dictionary[urlOrName]);
```

---

The other possible solution would be to create a module for each component that you're going to load dynamically and then add that component to the `entryComponents` of that module, that way, you could be able to import/download that module dynamically but I'm not sure if you could add that dynamic module to the root module dynamically or not ( the way router is doing it when lazyLoading !~~).

Angular used to be much simpler regarding the dynamic components before they introduced `AOT`, they honestly killed the simplicity with introducing `AOT`

Comment: You're one step ahead, but yeah... I'm afraid you're right. Even if i do manage to load the files dynamically, I'll still have to create them without having to declare them under declarations in the module. If i create PluginModule and declare that in the portal - changes to that module (new plugins) would still need a recompile of the portal?

Comment: Did some more digging. I could have the plugin loader compile the loaded stuff with a new instance of the JIT compiler, but i'd still have to use an undocumented and "subjected to change" method compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync on the @angular/compiler.